# How to automatically export data from Excel 2010 to Access 2010 using visual basic?

Tags: vba, excel, ado, excel-2010, ms-access-2010

I am trying to setup a button in Excel 2010 such that when it is clicked the data is sent to a  table in Access database. I have found many code samples online but none of them seem to work in my case.One of them said i need to give Execute access for certain usergroups,is that correct?Also,would it matter where the Excel workbook is or would it have to be in a certain location?I want it such that it can be any where in a user's computer and the visual basic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refe this link Export [Excel Worksheet to Access Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949063/export-excel-worksheet-to-access-table-accdb/16952570#16952570)

Comment: I am getting few errors. I have posted it below as an answer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answer was helpful you can vote for the answer.